# How to filter range of columns in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a data frame similar to the one below (with more string columns, I have included only one)

```
  phy chem lang math name
1   17   17   69    8    a
2   86   58   93   37    b
3   70   27   12   18    c
4   74   23   13   52    d
5   15   67   66   49    e
6   35   98   41   90    f
7   64   77   79   33    g
8   49    9   91   44    h
9   33   76    7  100    i
10  22   39   42   79    j
11   6   69   64   36    k
12  91   59    8   66    l
13  79   40   88   16    m
14  71   55   23   40    n
15  65    1    5   67    o
16  14   19   59    6    p
17  11   60   67   69    q
18  81   18   30   25    r
19  36   96   31   30    s
20  38   25   24   26    t
```

I am trying to keep the rows that (**ALL**) the values are in the range (50,100) **for the columns from phy:math only**. I have tried to use `dplyr` but I am getting only the first column filtered, i.e. I get values in next columns that are less than 50.

here is a code that you can reproduce the data, and the filter I am using. 
`

```
 phy<-sample(100,20)
 chem<-sample(100,20)
 lang<-sample(100,20)
 math<-sample(100,20)
 name<-letters[1:20]
 df<-data.frame(phy,chem,lang,math,name)
 subset(df,(df[,1:4]>50 | df[,1:4]<=100))
```

I have used the method of combining the filter by

```
filter(df, phys>=50 ,chem>=50 , math>=50,lang>=50)
```

and then to add the other condition, but I know there has to be a simple solution to that.

Note: I have ran a search on the site and published the question after one day of search.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df[apply(df[,1:4], 1, function(x) all(x > 50) & all(x < 100)),]
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can go through each row, find if min/max fall within your criteria and return a TRUE/FALSE.

```
ss <- apply(df[, 1:4], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {
  rg <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  if (min(rg) > 50 & max(rg) <= 100) TRUE else FALSE
  })

df[ss, ]

   phy chem lang math name
11  51   66   76   59    k
20  99   92   75  100    t
```

Comment: Thanks, when I applied it on the complete dataframe I got   `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` do you think that this could be due to empty cell?

Comment: @Athii I added a `na.rm` argument to `range()` which solves the NA issue.

Answer (score 1):

We create the logical matrix, negate (`!`) it, use `rowSums` to get the count of TRUE values for each row, convert to logical vector (`!`) where 0 values are TRUE (i.e. all values are within the range) and others FALSE, and subset the dataset.

```
df[!rowSums(!(df[1:4]>50 & df[1:4] <= 100), na.rm = TRUE),]
#    phy chem lang math name
#11  51   66   76   59    k
#20  99   92   75  100    t
```

Or with another efficient approach is to loop through the columns, get a `list` of logical `vector`s, `Reduce` it to a single `vector` by comparing the corresponding elements of each `vector` (`&`), use that to subset the dataset.

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[1:4], function(x) x > 50 & x <= 100)),]
#   phy chem lang math name
#11  51   66   76   59    k
#20  99   92   75  100    t
```

NOTE: Both of these methods should be very efficient as the first one uses the vectorized `rowSums` and second loops through columns instead of rows.

Comment: Both of them worked nicely on the complete dataset. Thank you so much

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't take care of potential NAs (Na rows are added to the result).

Comment: @Athi Glad to know that it works. There is `na.rm=TRUE` to take care of NAs.